# Limit of the mean value of a sequence of complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

Let $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complex numbers of the unit circle. Suppose that for all integers $k\geq 1$ :

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \overline{z_{k+l}}z_l \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 
\end{equation*}

We want to prove that :

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} z_l \underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{equation*}

I have computed :

\begin{equation*}
\left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} z_l \right|^2 = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^k \overline{z_{k-l}} z_l
\end{equation*}

And it thus suffices to show that :

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{l=0}^k \overline{z_{k-l}} z_l= o(k) \quad \text{as $k$ approaches $\infty$}
\end{equation*}

But I am having difficulty proving it... We would like the $-$ in the summation $\overline{z_{k-l}}$ to be a $+$ i.e. $ \overline{z_{k+l}}$... Does anyone have an idea?